# Hooking MariaDB DyanmicColumn into Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, mariadb, nosql

Been playing with MariaDB and really enjoy the NoSQL aspect of MariaDB in that we can add JSON into a column and do combined query for the Relational and the JSON part of a record. More info here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns/

I'm not trying to hook MariaDB into my code.
Following this page https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-mariadb/ been able to connect to MariaDB from Java code, add and edit data like a normal relational database.

Thought I'm not sure how to use the NoSQL aspect of it from Java.
Namely adding a Blob column that will contain JSON - what Java Data type represent it. And how do querying.

I've been doing alot of research on web and couldn't find anything. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: How about using @Query(value = "<query with nosql>", nativeQuery = true)? Adding this to your repositories, would enable you to use MariaDB queries.

Comment: You could also create a custom repository: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: any of the suggestions above helped you somehow?

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoAnderickJr, yes that's the last approach. though I've been of two minds about it. The reason I want to use dynamic column with relational database is to have flexibility with the data in that column, however by adding that approach, it will mean that I whenever I change the dynamic column contents, we'll need to update all the queries, as well as saves and updates, which really goes the opposite direction compared to the data flexibility I want to introduce. I'll play around with it some more and update you. =)

Comment: Great, let us know about your progress, if I find something that could help you, I post it here.

Comment: Currently I've been looking at MySQL JSON columns, which may offer a better approach. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html still looking.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the Query parameter to = "" ; Try it and post the results.

Comment: thanks @Mmelotti, same comment as in my question comment response.